# Get inner details of the TYPE of a method parameter using Roslyn

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-analysis, roslyn

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to get the inner details of the TYPE of a method parameter.

Say a method has the below definition

```
public void method1(Type1 param1, Type2 param2)
{
   ...
   ...
}
```

And `Type1` has the below definition

```
public class Type1
{
    public int prop1 {get; set;}
    public string prop2 {get; set;}
    public double prop3 {get; set;}
}
```

Then what I'm looking to get out of my sample tool is the list of properties of the class `Type1`. That is, I'm expecting my output to be

```
prop1 
prop2 
prop3
```

I could get a reference to the parameter by doing a `param.Type` but it is of type `IdentifierNameSyntax`. I'm able to get the name from it (`Type1` in this case) but not able to dig deeper INTO `Type1` to get the properties.

Is there any simple way to get that which I'm not yet aware of? Or do I have to do a search in the entire solution again using the name of the type that I got?

Thanks a lot!

**P.S.:** I did get a thought of using `Reflection` but all I have is a string (`Type1`) and not the actual TYPE. Not sure if I can use this or not.

**Update-1:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29035477/2377928) seems to be mildly close to what I'm expecting but from what I understand, the user only wants the name of the parameter type, not it's inner details.

**Update-2:** Adding sample code from my tool below. Unfortunately, I cannot post the actual code but the below sample is basically what I'm trying to do.
Update-2: Adding sample code from my tool below. Unfortunately, I cannot post the actual code but the below sample is basically what I'm trying to do.

```
var methodNode = (MethodDeclarationSyntax)node;
string paramClassName = string.Empty;

foreach (var param in methodNode.ParameterList.Parameters)
{
    paramClassName = param.Type.ToFullString();
    //GET Class details from the above class name
    GetInnerDetailsOfClassFromClassName(paramClassName);   //any way to do this?
}
```

Comment: You probably want to be looking at the *symbols* rather than the *syntax*. It would be easier to help you with that if you could show us the context of your code...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23878410/1034136

Comment: @JonSkeet Updated the code. Please check.

Comment: Right - have a look at the question Serj-Tm linked to. Basically it's the same deal - you want to get the symbol info via the semantic model.

Comment: @Serj-Tm The link that you shared is basically doing a full solution search again. But I was wondering if there was another way to do it because, when my program is at the above given code, it is already in the middle of a search. Hence want to avoid initiating another search inside a search :)

Comment: @AmoghNatu Create semantic model before search and put semantic model to search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Serj-Tm, @KevinPilch-Bisson and @JonSkeet. Your suggestions of using Symbols worked. This is my code below that returned the result I was expecting.

```
var methodNode = (MethodDeclarationSyntax)node;
string modelClassName = string.Empty;

foreach (var param in methodNode.ParameterList.Parameters)
{
    var metaDataName = document.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result.GetDeclaredSymbol(param).ToDisplayString();
//'document' is the current 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document' object
    var members = document.Project.GetCompilationAsync().Result.GetTypeByMetadataName(metaDataName).GetMembers();
    var props = (members.OfType<IPropertySymbol>());

    //now 'props' contains the list of properties from my type, 'Type1'
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        //some logic to do something on each proerty
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Once you find the `ParameterSyntax`, use `SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol` to get the `IParameterSymbol`, and then look at its `Type` to get the `ITypeSymbol` you are interested in.

Comment: Yes that is precisely what I did. :) thanks :) and thanks to @Serj-Tm too for his suggestion. I had not looked at the Symbols. Will post my code so that it can help others.